# Difference between "name" and "id" attributes in Kivy, and when should I use each

Tags: python, attributes, kivy

everybody. How's it going?

I couldn't find any post related to this, so here it goes:

I'm studying kivy and I got some questions about its foundation. What's the difference between "name:" and "id:" for referencing objects in Kivy?

---

Here's a sample of my code to use as an example. Note I'm referencing objects from "Screen" class using the "name" attribute, which is working pretty well, and I'm also able to reference objects' values from "TextInput" and "Button" using the "id" attribute:

```
<Button>:
    size_hint: 0.24, 0.1

<TextInput>:
    size_hint: 0.4, 0.1

ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'login_page'

        TextInput:
            id: email


        Button:
            id: login_button
            text: 'Go to main page'
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top": 0.2}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'main_page'
                root.transition.direction = 'left'
    Screen:
        name: 'main_page'
        
        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                text: 'Go to login page'
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top": 0.2}
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = 'login_page'
                    root.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of choice. The `name` attribute is part of the `Screen` class and is used by `ScreenManager` to manipulate its child `Screens`.

The `ids` are created by the `kv` builder (`kivy.lang.builder.Builder`) when `id` is encountered in a rule. The `id` is added to the `ids` dictionary of the root widget containing the `id`.

So, you can only use the `name` attribute for children of the `ScreenManager`. And you can use the `ids` only to access widgets that are part of a `kv` root widget rule.